Is there a faster way to concatenate strings in a column other than looping?
I know that if I have a single column table (call it tbl) with values like this:
col
---
A
B
C

and I want to get A,B,C as a single string, I can do this:
DECLARE @s varchar(20)
SELECT @s = @s + col + ',' FROM tbl

Actually, that gets me A,B,C, and I have to trim the ending comma, but that's minor.
But if I have a table with multiple columns like this:
first_name last_name position
---------- --------- --------
Steve      Austin    cook
Steve      Austin    dishwasher
Jaime      Sommers   waitress
Jaime      Sommers   manager

And I want to get this as the output:
first_name last_name position
---------- --------- --------
Steve      Austin    cook,dishwasher
Jaime      Sommers   waitress,manager

the only way I can think of to achieve it is to SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name, '' AS position into a new table, loop through the contents of that new table, and for each record, get the comma delimited list of positions the way I did in the first example and update each record with the joined list.
But if I have a table with a few hundred thousand records, that loop is going to take a very long time. It'll work, but I was hoping that maybe there's a better way to achieve it. Maybe with a CTE?
Thanks.

Looping is, quite literally, the slowest way.

Read about STRING_AGG

Unfortunately, my webhost is using SQL Server 2016, and String_agg is only there from 2017 onwards. Are there options other than string_agg?

You can use FOR XML trick to emulate the STRING_AGG, it should work on 2016, it's a bit less efficient since you need to setup an outer query containing the distinct values and an inner subquery that does the concatenation
